# Why is queueable not picking updated state?

Tags: apex, queueable-apex

Queueable class allows non primitive data type but they are also not picking updated state of object rather state that was passes to it when job was enqueued.

Below is my snippet of code which I was trying.

```java
//Queueable Class
public with sharing class QueueableClass1 implements System.Queueable {
    Account acc ;
    public QueueableClass1(Account a){
        this.acc = a;
    }
    public void execute (QueueableContext qc){
            System.debug('Account name in queueable class --> '  + acc.name);
    }    
}

// end of class
```

```java
// Console snippet
Account ac = [select id,name from account limit 1];
ac.name = 'Updating name';
update ac ;
System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass1(ac));
    
ac.name = 'Reversed update';
update ac;
//System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass1(ac));
```

I was expecting debug in Queueable class to print 'Reversed update' as async apex are called once sync transaction finishes.  But it prints 'Updating name'.
But if I put enqueue job in the end it prints correctly.
Now I am wondering Does doing System.enqueue job actually serializes the object when you pass them.

If yes then what is the use case for passing non primitive data types in Queueable class and ideally we should always pass list in it and query records to get latest state of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executions for Queueable, Batchable, Schedulable and Platform Events are handled by persisting the state of the (async) object at the point the relevant "execution request" method is called.

For queueables, the state of the queueable is persisted at the point you call `System.enqueueJob` (think of it as conversion to JSON which is then persisted in the database). Changes to the Apex data held in the queueable after that point do not impact the state persisted in the database. The same applies for the other types I listed above related to their equivalent "execution request" method (Batchable: `Database.executeBatch`, `System.scheduleBatch`; Schedulable: `System.schedule`; Platform Event: `EventBus.publish`).

There are plenty of use cases that require complex data to be stored, such as one or more `List` or `Map` with apex class instances. For example, we use a queueable with a list of a custom apex class where that class holds a single outgoing message's information (email template to use, ID(s) of the recipient(s) for the message). This helps us avoid hitting governor limits while sending the messages by splitting it over multiple executions (the queueable chains itself as needed).

Importantly `SObject`s are not the only complex apex data types.

As per the comments, there is similar handling for Finalizers, though the "execution request" point is implicitly when the queueable exits (successfully or with failure). This is why the Finalizer state can appear to change (but really it doesn't since it is persisted after control returns from your queueable).

PS: For a Batchable that implements Database.Stateful, the state is re-persisted after each call to `start` or `execute`.

Comment: Note: Technically, Finalizer is async, but automatically updates. However, that's because that's how it was designed to be used.

Comment: AFAIK the Finalizer state is persisted at the point the queueable completes or exits due to error, this effectively being the equivalent of the execution method for the Finalizer, but I must say I have only implemented the Finalizer and Queueable as a single object.

Comment: Correct. The Finalizer doesn't serialize at the same point as Future, Batchable, Queueable, or Schedulable. You can freely update the object until the end of the transaction. I was just pointing it out in contrast, since you said *All types of async executions*, which may be misleading :D

Comment: Hopefully that is no longer the case...

Comment: When you say persisted does that means they are being serialized?  Thanks for pointing out @sfdcfox because that would have been my next questions as in finalizer i was able to always see updated state.
Could you also point a scenario where I might use non primitive in Queueable.